# how to get button element using Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am writing a selenium code in java that will insert a user name and password and will login to a site using chrome:

```
WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.id("usernameInput"));
    query.sendKeys("****");
    WebElement query2 = driver.findElement(By.id("passwordInput"));
    query2.sendKeys("****");
    Thread.sleep(1500);

    WebElement query3 = driver.findElement(By.className(btn z-btn-default  pull-right));
    query3.click();
```

i cant get the login button to clicked.
i used the inspect element of the button to search for id or something else to use but with no successes.
i am adding a screenshot from the inspect element

[image]

Comment: Why not using xpath or css selector?

Answer (score 0):

Use  This Hope It will help you

```
WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.id("usernameInput"));
query.sendKeys("****");
WebElement query2 = driver.findElement(By.id("passwordInput"));
query2.sendKeys("****");
Thread.sleep(1500);
WebElement query3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='btn z-btn-default  pull-right']"));
query3.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

selenium class name takes only one class name at a time. Try with css selector or xpath as given below.

```
WebElement query3 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.z-btn-default.pull-right"));
```

or

```
WebElement query3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn z-btn-default  pull-right']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the other values in xpath

```
//input[@type='Submit'][@value='LOGIN']
```

code:

```
WebElement query3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='Submit'][@value='LOGIN']"));
query3.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're unable to click on the button as it seems to be disabled, looking at the html you've provided.

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" ...>
```

I think you need to find out under what case the submit button would become enabled, and accordingly write your selenium test.

Also, in case you're not able to uniquely identify this submit button via its attributes, selenium provides a `submit()` method to submit the form, like below:

```
webelement.submit();
```

Refer the documentation on [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#user-input-filling-in-forms) page.

HTH...

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these below code.

From your `html`, Your `LOGIN` button is inside the `<input>` tag. So your `xpath` should start from `<input>` tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='LOGIN'][@type='submit']")).click();
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Start xpath with `<input>` tag along with `value` and `type` attributes.

Note:- Instead of using `absolute xpath` Use `Relative xpath`

> OR

You can click `LOGIN` button using `JavaScript Executor` Method.

```
WebElement login_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='LOGIN'][@type='submit']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", login_button);
```

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's resolved your issue :)